# Significant Drop in Page Speed Performance - Seeking Insight

Tags: performance, optimization, pagespeed

**Issue: Significant Drop in Page Speed Performance**

We have been consistently monitoring our site's pagespeed performance, and this month we've noticed a notable decline compared to the previous month.

Last month, our PLP page's performance score was 77. However, upon recent evaluation, the current score has dipped to 67. Surprisingly, there haven't been any major changes made to the underlying codebase.

[PageSpeed report on 31st August](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiTNA.png)
[PageSpeed report on 3rd October](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNaf7.png)

We're reaching out to seek insights and expertise on potential factors contributing to this decline.

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this doc for some possible explanations of variability in the Lighthouse results: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/variability